# Customizing the VSCode file-explorer panel as a hyperlinked document

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to customize the VSCode file-and-folder explorer area
so that, for a particular folder, its contents appear as words within
an *editable text area* ? 
The idea is to display file and folder names as *marked words* [e.g. in double brackets]
linked to the relevant file or folder content, which on click is displayed on the right-hand panel;
that is, marked words placed among other *un-marked* explanatory text,
thus facilitating the dynamic placement of the file-names on the folder contents-area according to some easily changeable pattern.
Briefly, to move beyond the rigid alphabetically-ordered list of folder-contents and make it a hyperlinked document.

Comment: you can write such a View yourself, it is a bit of work but can be done